# Count condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two list of users, `user` and `mentioned` and I want to count the number of times `u1` has mentioned `u2` also the count of number of times `u1` has mentioned `u3` , also the count of how many times `u3` has mentioned `u2` and so on the list is quite big with up to 1000+ distinct users so I prefer generic answer. The table will look something like that,

```
user   mentioned 
u1      u2
u1      u2
u1      u2
u1      u3
u3      u2
```

The final result should look something like that

```
user   mentioned  count
 u1      u2         3 
 u1      u3         1
 u3      u2         1
```

Should I use a for loop and for each user , I'm confused about which approach should I take

Comment: use Group by user,mentioned Clause

Comment: Give the code a go and post it. Will be eaiser to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple aggregation:

```
select user, mentioned, count(*)
from yourTable
group by user, mentioned
```

Notice that `user` is a reserved word, so it would be better to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you! It was really simple

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
select user, mentioned, count(*)
from table
group by user, mentioned
```